# IOS animation in this video

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, uicollectionview

I am stuck in below task where I need similar animation in `UITableView`.
But I am also not sure what component used in this video (UITableView or `UICollectionView`)?

[Animated component](https://streamable.com/1nvvm)

Any leads highly appreciated

Comment: seems like  Collectionview and using scrollViewDidScroll (vertical one). As far as I see, there is a measurement there, which tells controller to use offset and scroll if distance is > < . Remind me  about a carousel :)

Comment: @user3344236 but not the whole cell is getting animated only images when clicking in text.

Comment: There are actually 2 controllers, see the text of below going under images scroll. What can be easy done if you use delegate or other methods, you invoke upper scroll to go up down with distance. I suppose bottom part is UITableView and also you can have another UITableView or CollectionView in upper part. Hope this helps. Personally I disregard using 2 UITableViews in same controller, but... try

Comment: try also to figure out a vertical scroller as in https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView Any carousel that has delegates like didscrollatindex, didchangedindex, scrolltoindex is appropriate.

Comment: @user3344236 Thanks I am trying to build two carousels and connect to each other. Hope this will fix this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

First up, there are multiple ways to implement this.

If the video shows the exact output you expect, you can achieve this with two `UITableView`s. One for the names on the bottom and one for the images on top.

Now, within the `scrollViewDidScroll` method, listen to the scroll changes within the `tableView` that contains the text and scroll the `tableView` with the images accordingly. If you're going for constant sized cells, the scroll coeffecient would be the `sizeOfCellWithImage:sizeOfCellWithText`

Comment: Thanks but also I have to make a circular table view for expected output.

Comment: Achieving cyclic scrolling is quite simple.
Return a lot of rows in numberOfRowsInSection - say numberOfImages * 1000. 
And in cellForRowAtIndexPath, use indexPath.row % numberOfImages to get the right index to display

Comment: Thanks but Any idea how to stick with 1st row always like in golden background?

Comment: Multiple ways there again as well. You can have a transparent `tableView` with a golden background behind it. Or, have a transparent golden view on top of the `tableView`. Please upvote and accept my answer

Comment: I have tried to build this component but the problem what is the best way to scroll top view from bottom view if only 0 index is changing.  

So far I have tried :  https://streamable.com/xa3i7

Comment: That was what I had explained in my answer. You need to hook up the scrolls of the tables in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method